# How to exclude a directory from deleting using ADB shell?

Tags: android, shell, adb

I am using `adb shell rm -rf /sdcard/*` to delete all contents from SDCARD right now. But I want to exclude a folder named Download from deleting. Can someone help me into this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the name of the folder you want to delete. If it is inside sdcard directory, then run:

```
adb shell rm -rf /sdcard/Download
```